# Update values of a row to the max of old and new value

Tags: postgresql

In SQLite I am doing something like

```
UPDATE some_table SET
    some_string = "hund",
    score = MAX(score, 42)
    hair_density = hair_density + 1
WHERE some_criteria = 31337;
```

Is there a similar feature in PostgreSQL?

From my reading of the docs and my experiments MAX() is only available in select statements. Like:

```
SELECT MAX(score) from some_table;
```

Is the an equivalent in PostgreSQL to the way I use MAX() in SQLite?

Comment: I know it is not standard SQL. I sets the value of score to the MAX(old value of score, 42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that `max()` usage is used to get the bigger of the two numbers, the equivalent is `greatest()` in Postgres

```
UPDATE some_table 
  SET some_string = 'hund',
      score = greatest(score, 42)
      hair_density = hair_density + 1
WHERE some_criteria = 31337;
```

Additionally: string (varchar) values have to be enclosed with single quotes `'`- double quotes are only for identifiers (e.g. column or table names). So  `"hund"` refers to a column, but `'hund'` is a string constant.